# Перелистывание большого текста Android

Tags: android

Подскажите как реализовать перелистывание большого текста, как в видео:
https://youtu.be/TLgoEC4uXAA

Answer (score 1):

То что вам нужно называется `ViewPager`, это стандартные элемент. Для его  использования вам понядобяться фрагменты и собственно сам `ViewPager`

Создаете фрагменты которые хотите листать, создаете адаптер для `ViewPager`
и готово:

вот пример из урока по `ViewPager`:

Создаем фрагмент

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

  static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";

  int pageNumber;
  int backColor;

  static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
    pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
    return pageFragment;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);

    Random rnd = new Random();
    backColor = Color.argb(40, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);

    TextView tvPage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPage);
    tvPage.setText("Page " + pageNumber);
    tvPage.setBackgroundColor(backColor);

    return view;
  }
}
```

создаем активити с адаптером:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  static final String TAG = "myLogs";
  static final int PAGE_COUNT = 10;

  ViewPager pager;
  PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected, position = " + position);
      }

      @Override
      public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
          int positionOffsetPixels) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
      }
    });
  }

  private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

  }

}
```

Более детально можете посмотреть в этом [уроке](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/228-urok-125-viewpager.html)